# I want to highlight my buttons from my nav-bar Please help me out

Tags: html, css, navigation, highlight

I'm trying to make my navigation bar, highlighted, I mean I must highlight the button of the active page that I'm surfing at the moment.
I've tried to in this way, but it's not working out.
I have this HTML code as my navigation menu:

```
<code>
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="first">
        <a href="index.htm">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="hasdropdown" href="collections/catalog/catalog.htm">Catalog</a>                       
    </li>

    <li>                            
        <a class="hasdropdown" href="collections/ocassions/ocassions.htm">Ocassions</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="hasdropdown" href="collections/specials/specials.htm">Specials</a>
    </li>

    <li>                            
        <a href="pages/plants.htm">Plants</a>                              
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="pages/exotic.htm">Exotic</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="pages/contact.htm">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and I also have this CSS

```
#header #navblock ul.nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #b23758;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}

#header #navblock ul.nav li a.active:visited {
    background-color: #b23758;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}

<br/>
```

They just don't work out! Please if anyone can explain how to do it right?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you just trying to highlight the current page? If so you could just add a `class="active"` to the li belonging to the current page and set your css on that `li.active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to add a class `.current` to the page that is currently being browsed.  So, if the user is on the home page:

```
<li class="first">
        <a href="index.htm" class="current">Home</a>
    </li>
```

Then, configure the `.current` class as however you like:

```
.current {
    background-color: #b23758;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Ref.  http://alistapart.com/article/keepingcurrent

Comment: oh, it worked!!! thx a lot for the help, it was so easy.. I just didn't figured out in the right way!!!

Answer (score 1):

This will most likely help you: http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/highlighting-current-page-with-css

Basically the idea is that you add id to each of your pages like this:

```
<body id="home">
```

And since you already have navigation as an unsorted list, similary to this:

```
<ul id="navlist">
    <li><a href="index.html" id="homenav">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html" id="prodnav">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.html" id="faqnav">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html" id="connav">contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then it is possible to use css like this:

```
body#home a#homenav,
body#products a#prodnav,
body#faq a#faqnav,
body#contact a#connav {
    color: #fff;
    background: #930;
}
```

Which defines that if body id="home", then link with id="homenav" has the following style.

Comment: Reason I find this solution better than .class versions is that the menu part of the code remains the same on every page. Which makes it easier to maintain. Based on body id or content id, corresponding nav element can be easily highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to achieve, you should add a class to your button of your active page.

Let say you're on the Catalog page. So your link should look like

```
<li>
    <a class="hasdropdown active" href="collections/catalog/catalog.htm">Catalog<a>                       
</li>
```

In this exemple, your link Catalog has the class "active". And now, you can set your css for this class, and so, for this button :

```
.active {
    background-color: #b23758;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    }
```

Of course, this means each page of your website has to display a menu with the class "active" on the the corresponding link.

Comment: oh, it worked!!!
thx a lot for the help, it was so easy..
I just didn't figured out in the right way!!!